# Jquery getJSON sorts my data by id automatically

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, sorting, getjson

I have a combo box that triggers a jquery function on change, it calls a  php script which brings the results from the database sorted by name not by id (table cities) and creates a json file with the id and the name of the  city.
The  problem comes with a  $.getJSON(url, data) function, it retrieves all the json encoded data fine, but it is seems to be sorting the data  automatically by the id

for instance if the php page generates

```
id  name
3   Dania Beach
1   Miami
2   Weston
```

after jquery getJSON it  sorts it by id

```
id  name
1   Miami
2   Weston
3   Dania Beach
```

Is there a way to disable  sorting? or how can in preserve the order by name?

Comment: Can you please show us the exact JSON string that is being generated by your PHP?

Comment: What browser are you using? Chrome will re-sort objects by key id indiscriminately. Other browsers, like FireFox, will leave them be. Joe Coder has the answer right below.

Comment: Here is the link as you can see for florida the json comes in order but once i use the jquery it sorts it by id [link](http://www.zapotestudio.com/prueba_clientes/sfcycler/cities/getlist/FL)

Comment: Now that you've shown your code, I've updated my answer below.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is an associative array: order does not matter.  The following JSON objects are equivalent:

```
{
    "3" : "Danie Beach",
    "1" : "Miami",
    "2" : "Weston"
}

{
    "1" : "Miami",
    "2" : "Weston",
    "3" : "Danie Beach"
}
```

If you need an ordering, you should instead embed an array within the JSON:

```
{
    "beaches" : [
        {"key" : "3", "value" : "Danie Beach"},
        {"key" : "1", "value" : "Miami"},
        {"key" : "2", "value" : "Weston"}
    ]
}
```

Example Usage:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    ...
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        jQuery.each(data.beaches, function(i, beach) {
            alert(i+': beach['+beach.key+'] = '+beach.value);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Genius! Although I still think its a little odd that it thinks they are the same when they clearly aren't ;) Thanks reordered the array keys as strings.