# jQuery.parseJSON disordered array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

*Initial PHP ARRAY Storing attributes as values and respective id's on key*

```
Array
(
[979] => Pict Model
[962] => Brand
[494] => Dimensions
[980] => Capacity
[981] => Power
[982] => List Price
[983] => Warrenty
[975] => USB Connection
[976] => Self Cleaning
[977] => Double Glass Door
[978] => Steam Function
[974] => Electricity Type
)
```

In my Code below, **comparable_attr** holds the json encoded array.
After that, as i **console.log(comparable_attr)** This gives me a json of order as of php array.

Then, after i parseJSON and then console.log it gave me data in different order.

```
var comparable_attr = '<?php echo json_encode($_comparable_attributes); ?>';
   if(comparable_attr.length != 0){       //check for empty json
      console.log(comparable_attr);
          var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(comparable_attr);
                console.log(obj);
}
```

**Problem :** i want to achieve it in same order after i parseJSON.

**The result obtained :**

*First Console.log(comparable_attr) gives:*

```
{"979":"Pict Model","962":"Brand","494":"Dimensions","980":"Capacity","981":"Power","982":"List Price","983":"Warrenty","975":"USB Connection","976":"Self Cleaning","977":"Double Glass Door","978":"Steam Function","974":"Electricity Type"}
```

*Second Console.log(obj) gives :*

```
 Object { 494="Dimensions", 962="Brand", 974="Electricity Type", more...}
```

[image]

**Edited** :

What i have found is, it shorted according to my attribute id, which i need in the same order as it is in array.

Comment: Take a look at this question, it may help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574068/jquery-getjson-sorts-my-data-by-id-automatically

Comment: yeah quite odd indeed, maybe related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21216391/prevent-json-encode-associative-array-sorting

Comment: @Ghost it's not odd at all, it's a natural consequence of JS objects being explicitly _unordered_.

Comment: @Alnitak yeah thanks for shedding light on this

Answer (score 3):

When you convert a PHP spare array into JSON and subsequently into a JS variable you will get a JS `Object`, not an array, and JS objects are explicitly an *unordered* set of key value pairs.

If you wish to preserve the order you will need to rearrange the data on the PHP side first, perhaps as:

```
Array(
    Array([979] => Pict Model),
    Array([962] => Brand),
    ...
)
```

Note however that if you do this you will lose the ability to directly lookup the data by key, as the resulting JS object would look like:

```
[
  { "979": "Pict Model" },  // NB: all JS keys are strings
  { "962": "Brand" },
  ...
]
```

An alternative might be to send your existing array as is, but also send a second array that is just the ordered list of keys.  The former can be used for key-based lookup, the latter to determine the correct order:

```
json_encode(array(
    'data' => $_comparable_attributes,
    'order' => array_keys($_comparable_attributes)
));
```

Comment: what about swapping key and values form my array as both are string to me ? i solved that way (as it didn't sorted the alphabet being on key) but is it right to do this way ?

Comment: @K.C. hard to say without knowing why the order matters.  Swapping the keys and values will still give you an object that's not sorted.

Comment: But Swapping gave me the same order as of php Array. Yeah, actually ordering matters here, it's that kinda case. Anyways Thank you.

Comment: @K.C. you can't rely on that ordering being preserved - in other browsers it could well be different.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript’s json object order is inplementation dependant. You could try it in the `console`:

```
a = {2:'a', 1:'b'}
Object {1: "b", 2: "a"}
```

To solve your problem I would suggest you to prevent auto sorting by:

```
array_reduce(
  $a, 
  function($carry, $item) use(&$a) { 
    $carry[] = [key($a), $item]; next($a); return $carry; 
  }, 
  []
)
```

This will wrap your initial array into array containing `[key, val]` items.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, JSON representation of objects are _not_ automatically sorted by key.  It's implementation dependant.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. Updated an answer.

Comment: Also, your output will be `[[key1, val1], [key2, val2], ...]` - not the `[[key1 => X, val1 => Y], ...]` associative array you've shown.  The latter is an array of objects, the former an array of arrays.

Comment: @Alnitak thatnks for explanation the difference between arrays and objects.

Comment: Also `array_map(function($k, $v) { return array($k, $v); }, array_keys($a), $a)` is simpler than using `array_reduce`.

Comment: `array_reduce` is flexible. My intention was not to give a ready-to-go solution, but to show a technique.