# jQuery parseJSON not keep order of json keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Json string:

```
"{"detail":{"01":0,"02":0,"03":0,"04":0,"05":"-","06":"-","07":"-","08":"-","09":"-","10":"-","11":"-","12":"-"}}"
```

jQuery.parseJSON result:

```
{detail:{10:"-", 11:"-", 12:"-", '01':0, '02':0, '03':0, '04':0, '05':"-", '06':"-", '07':"-", '08':"-", '09':"-"}}
```

I do not know why parseJSON changes the order of keys (10, 11, 12, 01, 02,... instead of 01,02,03,...). How can I keep the order in this case?

Comment: answer is very simple ....  objects have no order. Use arrays if order and sort are important

Comment: Found something for you **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12574228/2065039)** in support to @charlietfl's comment..

Comment: Thank you, @charlietfl, Guruprasad Rao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not know why parseJSON changes the order of keys (10, 11, 12, 01, 02,... instead of 01,02,03,...).

Most browsers iterate over properties in the following order:

- integer indexes<sup>(*)</sup> in ascending order
- strings in creation order

<sub>*: A positive 32-bit integer is considered to be an integer index</sub>

However, is is implementation specific and not required by the language standard. There are likely environments that have a completely different behavior.

(Related: [Does ES6 introduce a well-defined order of enumeration for object properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30076219/218196))

So `10`, `11`, `12` are listed first because they are integers. `01`, `02`, etc are following because they are treated as strings.

> How can I keep the order in this case?

You cannot. You have to use an array, which should be rather trivial in your case since your keys are basically consecutive numbers.

Comment: I knew my problem. Thank you very much, Felix Kling.